# Restore window size to original fixed size in JavaFx 8

Tags: javafx, resize, window, javafx-8, maximize-window

I have the following code which maximizes the window when the maximize button is clicked (the green one in the title bar). However it does not comes back to the original size (900x600) when it is clicked again while in maximize position. I see only the left side is shrinked.

```
//set the original size        
final Scene homeScene = new Scene(homePane,900,600);
```

...

```
    primaryStage.maximizedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean t, Boolean t1) {

            primaryStage.setX(bounds.getMinX());
            primaryStage.setY(bounds.getMinY());
            primaryStage.setWidth(bounds.getWidth());
            primaryStage.setHeight(bounds.getHeight());
        }
    });
```

How do I get back the original position ? The "Changed" method is not triggered when maximize button is clicked again , otherwise I would have set the original size programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Following code works just fine to listen for the maximized state of a `Stage`:

```
primaryStage.maximizedProperty().addListener((w,o,n)->System.out.println(n));
```

Are using a custom (undecorated) `Stage`, then you might want to take a look at the [Undecorator](https://github.com/in-sideFX/Undecorator) which has done just this.

Comment: This code behaves exactly same as the code I posted. It prints true when I maximize the window but does not print anything when I click on the maximize button again. Am I missing anything.  I am using Normal Stage with all the buttons on the top.

Comment: In my case it prints `false` too. What Java Version are you using, Operating System?

Comment: Java 8 , Mac. But its good enough if works for just windows. Lemme try in win.

Comment: If you think this is a JavaFX bug, you should file a bug: https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/

Comment: Totally - May be I would directly reach out to the developers at ORCL I know :)

Answer (score 0):

I used this code

```
@FXML
    private void btnMaximize(MouseEvent event) {
        Stage s = (Stage) borderpane.getScene().getWindow();
        s.setFullScreen(true);
    }
```

```
@FXML
    private void btnRestoreDown(MouseEvent event) {
        Stage s = (Stage) borderpane.getScene().getWindow();
        s.setFullScreen(false);
    }
```

Hope it may help someone who sees this post